# Updating record with global unique identification value

Tags: update

Using the Global record Id set on record creation I can update the record within the developer console, but in the class it throws an error...

Code below

Get rec to update:

```
List<Session__c> sessionRec = [SELECT ID, Name, SessionStartTime__c, SessionEndTime__c FROM Session__c WHERE ID =:sessionId];
```

Updating values:

```
SessionRec[0].SessionStartTime__c = System.now();
SessionRec[0].SessionEndTime__c = System.now().addSeconds(TTL);
update sessionRec;
```

Any ideas why this runs in dev console but not in class?

Edit:

```
private final Integer TTL = 3000;
private final String NAME = 'sid';

Cookie sessionCookie = ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get(NAME);
if (sessionCookie != null) {
    String sessionId = sessionCookie.getValue();
    //Previous code here
}
```

Comment: Is that because there is mistake in your code?

Comment: Could you elaborate? As I stated it runs in the developer console. Hard to believe that faulty code runs in console and is only picked up within the class.

Comment: Can you post exact code in your class, and which error appears? Without that it is hard to understand. Where does TTL/session id come?

Comment: Added rest of code

Comment: Error is important as well. And what if sessionId is null?

Comment: Calls a redirect method.

Comment: Error messages would be great for me too, all I get in my debug logs are "success" (thanks salesforce, lol).

Comment: @Y12K did you check sessionId in sessionCookie is correct ?

Comment: @NITHESHK Yes, even hardcoded an ID from the database for testing, same result...

Comment: @Y12K   //Previous code here  means which code, can u update full code.

Comment: That is the full code, note the "EDIT".

Comment: @Y12K    ID sessionId =(id) sessionCookie.getValue(); try with this